# Jupyter `export as html` does not use my customized theme and changes the font colors

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I use a dark theme ([custom.css](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/master/custom.css)) for the jupyter notebooks. When I use nbconvert either through the command line or from the menu, it gives me an html file with a different font colors.

I read about it on the developer GitHub page but I did not understand how I should apply the suggested changes. Here is the link to GitHub page:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/commit/7e4354fbd9349ac2d045b9a4693d3704b382cea6

My attempt to copy the handlers.py to the resource folder in nbconvert directory did not work.